# What is the difference in execution time for allocating to the heap vs the stack?

Tags: c++, performance

I am a little stuck on this question in my homework: 
*Write three functions in C or C++: one that declares a large array statically, one that declares the same large array on the stack, and one that creates the same large array from the heap. Call each of the subprograms a large number of times {at least 100,000) and output the time required by each. Explain the results.*

```
    int main(void)  
{
    int staticIntArray[ARRAY_SIZE];//array on the stack
    int *ptrArray = new int[ARRAY_SIZE]; // pointer on the stack but array on the heap.
    double timeItTakes;
    clock_t tStart = clock();
    fillWithRandomNumbers(staticIntArray, ARRAY_SIZE);
    double time = static_cast<double>(clock() - static_cast<double>(tStart)/static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
    printf ("Array on stack time is %.10f\n", time);
    clock_t tStart2 = clock();
    fillWithRandomNumbers(ptrArray, ARRAY_SIZE);
    double time2 = static_cast<double>(clock() - static_cast<double>(tStart2)/static_cast<double>(CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
    printf ("Array on heap time is %.10f\n", time2);
    //cout << "Array on the heap time is " << (timeIntStack - time(NULL));
}
void fillWithRandomNumbers(int intArray[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        intArray[i] = rand();
}
```

The output is:

```
Array on stack time is 1.9990000000
Array on heap time is 2.9980000000
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What I understand is that the stack is much smaller allocation of memory that is for local variables and parameters while the heap is a large pool of dynamically allocated memory. Here are my questions...
Does using the random class affect the time it takes for the function to execute? Is allocating large arrays on the stack slower because there is less memory available?

I am not trying ask you to do my homework but I just need a little help clarifying the concepts... Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 6):

First, allow me a slight rant.

The assignment -- presumably in a C++ programming class -- is a bad one.  It is diverting your focus to the performance implications of dynamic allocation versus static or automatic allocation, but that is not the **main** reason you should choose one form of allocation over another.  Rather, lifetime and visibility requirements in addition to ownership semantics should be considered long before performance when deciding how to allocate a chunk of memory.  Even setting this argument aside, the test is still invalid because the hardware you run the code on, the size of the individual elements in the array and the array itself, the operating system, how the kernel blocks when allocating and the optimization the compiler is permitted to employ are all going to effect the execution speed in any **real** code you write.  But this assignment seems to be suggesting that you should conclude, "see?  Dynamic allocation is slower.  We should never use it."  That reasoning is incorrect and teaches you to employ premature optimization.

OK, end of my rant.

On to your assignment.  You are doing two main things wrong.

1. The assignment never asks you to *populate* the array.
2. The assignment asks you to allocate the arrays 10k times, but you're doing it only once.
3. (Bonus!) The assignment doesn't ask you to deallocate the dynamically allocated array -- but it should.

Comment: Makes me wonder who teaches C++ in college.  People who couldn't cut it as real programmers?

Comment: typically Computer Science professors are not software engineers.  There is a sharp difference between being a software engineer and a computer scientist.  For starters computer science is the science of performing computations and has zero to do with a computer, it is just coincidence that the tool that is used happens to be called a computer.  This is a distinction most people do not make, and is part of the reason why people rant on Computer Science majors for not being expert coders.  CS people understand the semantics and rules of a language and how to prove that language's

Comment: correctness.  A software engineer implements the abstraction that the scientist has proved to be valid.

Comment: @Woot4Moo:  Now you've gone and evoked my soapbox...  I get the distinction between a computer scientist and a software engineer.  And I don't just rant on CS grads for not bheing "expert" coders -- they aren't even *competent* coders.  I graduated with a CS degree from what was a top CS school at that time.  I can tell you that I did not get anything from my education that prepared me to be a professional programmer.

Comment: In my opinion, college programming courses are taught by incompetent programmers, by and large.  And they produce incompetent programmers.  The goal of CS programs, therefore, must be not to produce people who can contribute to industry, but to academia.  CS schools do not make programmers, they make professors.  It does not help the state of the art, the industrial landscape, or the economy to produce incompetent programmers.

Comment: Moreover, even if the goal of CS programs -- not to produce programmers, but "scientists" -- is a valid one, then teaching programming languages in these courses is pointless.  Why do CS programs have C++ classes int he first place?

Comment: I do enjoy a good soapbox :) .  So to build on what you said.  Let us take a CS curriculum like that of Stanford.  They offer a variety of things to get involved in, such as theory, AI, and software engineering.  I would say the point of teaching programming courses is so that CS majors, many of whom have to solve mathematical problems, will be able to create an automated way of solving them.  Granted I write code for a living, and I also go to grad school, courses at the masters level (in terms of SE) are more like the real world than the generalized things you learn in undergrad

Comment: I find my algorithms and data structure course has come in quite handy when evaluating code for performance problems.  I would say that if you were a part of a CS curriculum at the masters level with a focus on software engineering you would be learning practical skills.  Now to reply to "Why do CS programs have C++ classes int he first place? "  Using a programming language to describe how a system functions is probably easier then pulling out diagrams of logical structures and saying "Go ahead there is a stack tell me what you can do with it"

Comment: @Woot4Moo:  Well, 1225 days later (something pulled me here), and I still largely agree with everything I said.  However, I do think you're right in that the objective to a CS undergrad program isn't to produce industrial programmers, but academicians -- a C++ programming class exists simply to express & test ideas, much in the same way that Physics students are required to take Calculus.

Comment: I think what's needed is a new kind of school whose sole purpose is to produce great programmers.  Kind of like a technical school, but focused only on programming, engineering, hardware and the like, and very a high-quality education.  Classes would be taught by experts in their fields -- real, working programmers -- and would cover a range of topics typically only learned after being in industry for many years.

Comment: @JohnDibling, interesting observation. Do you have any links that elaborate on educating people in this manner would work best? As someone who has worked in both academic and industry jobs I'm very interested in reading more on this topic. This is something I'm currently writing some blog material about.

Comment: @shuttle87:  I don't have any literature -- only my own experiences.  I'd be interested in reading it as well.

Comment: @JohnDibling well nothing like being brought back to something with 3 years of hindsight.  I still think that is dangerous, for example I have had the "privilege" of going to several security conferences,where people exclaim that CS degrees should focus on computer security.  However, to your point about a trade school of sorts, that could work.  Assuming we don't mind that students are only learning the "current" programming languages and problems.

Answer (score 3):

You are only allocating your arrays once, at the start of the program, and only writing their contents in the fillWithRandomNumbers loop. The program didn't measure allocation at all; for this to happen, the `new` operator should have been within a loop.

Try to follow the assignment here: Write three *functions*, with each function allocating the array in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

First you are not doing what the assignment asks for.

Second you should expect the stack allocation to be much faster, since the only thing that is does internally is to move the stack pointer.